# Restrict access to git master branch in Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

We are using Visual Studio Code for development with a private GitServer. Are there any method available to restrict access to  master  branch, so that all developers can develop on their local and push to individual remote branch but may not push to master branch themselves. Master branch will be managed only by few privileged users

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to handle that with branch permissions on the central repo. Your users can do whatever they want on their local repo but wouldn't be able to push any changes they made on master. You can probably do some pre-commit shenanigans but that is more of a pain to manage.

Github, Bitbucket and even TFS all allow management of branch level permissions.